# Notepad++ and regex: how to UPPERCASE specific part of a string / find / replace

Tags: regex, text, format, notepad++, uppercase

i've been trying for some time now to get this working, but i can't find a solution to this task myself - ok, i'm very new to regex-use but quite interested to learn, hope anybody has some brainfood for me...

my text-string is like this - without the numbers...

Word1 Word2 word3 (some words in brackets)
Word1 (some words in brackets)
word1, Word2 (some words in brackets)

means: 
an **indefinite number of words** (sometimes just one, maybe 2 to 4, sometimes separated by commas) followed by a string in round brackets (the value in the brackets should not change)

what i'm looking for is two different regexes - to use with **FIND and REPLACE in notepad++**
**1. only uppercasing of all the words before the brackets

2. like no.1 + adding html-tags)**

should look like: 1:

WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 (some words in brackets)
WORD1 (some words in brackets)
WORD1, WORD2 (some words in brackets)

and 2:

EDIT: 2nd html-tag was at the wrong position, now right!

%htmltag%WORD1 WORD2 WORD3%/htmltag% (some words in brackets)
%htmltag%WORD1%/htmltag% (some words in brackets)
%htmltag%WORD1, WORD2%/htmltag% (some words in brackets)

hope somebody could help me - thax a lot beforhand!

Comment: do you have any examples of regexs you've tried?

Comment: i tried for example this: ^([\w*]*?)\s[(] - but it only finds the beginning of each line and not all the words till the 1st round bracket - btw: it's ROUND BRACKETS !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For part 1 you can use

```
Find:  ^(.*?)(?=\()
Replace \U\1
```

Make sure regex is selected

for part 2

```
Find: ^(.*?)(\(.*?\))
Replace:%htmltag%\1%/htmltag%\2
```

which takes

```
WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 (some words in brackets)
WORD1 (some words in brackets)
WORD1, WORD2 (some words in brackets)
```

and converts it to

```
%htmltag%WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 %/htmltag%(some words in brackets)
%htmltag%WORD1 %/htmltag%(some words in brackets)
%htmltag%WORD1, WORD2 %/htmltag%(some words in brackets)
```

Comment: Keith, this is great! You are my hero ;-) Any ideas for part2 as well?

Comment: sorry to bother you again...this was close, but i editedt my question meanwhile- had the 2nd html-tag at the wrong position: i only want the UPPERCASED WORDS from before between tags (see above) - or even, if you know a solution for that too: SOME UPPERCASED WORDS IN A ROW followed by other words...-different for each line- and only the UPPERCASED should be set between tags, if possible??

Comment: just a sec...I'll do that

Comment: there you go, just does the html tags for the words at the beginning

Comment: part1 works perfectly, THANX!  as for part2: do i interprete the find-regex correctly: we are searching for a string until the round bracket i.e. /1 followed by a second string /2 - then you try to reuse those two with the tags...should work, but somehow doesn't, hm??

Comment: maybe also an extra search for SOME UPPERCASE WORDS in a line...that could be captured, reused and altered would be cool - but how?

Comment: not sure what the problem is? in notepad I take your example text and convert it fine,  will show in my answer

Comment: yeah, now it works for me as well - don't know what it was before...GREAT! THANX AGAIN!

Comment: If you're looking to do the opposite, substitute \U with \L.  For example, searching for `([A-Z])([A-Z]*)` and replacing with `\U\1\L\2' will convert the word to lower case apart from the first letter.

Answer (score 9):

### Scenario 1: generate uppercase for matches on Notepad++

You can use a regex like this:

```
\(.*?\)|(\w+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bM0xR3/3)**

Then on your `Find/Replace` dialog you can put `\U\1` on `Replace with`. So, if you go over `Find Next` you can replace the string to generate the uppercase output.

[image]

### Scenario 2: concatenate tags on each line

You can use this regex:

```
(.+?)\[
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bM0xR3/4)**

[image]

Comment: hey fede, thanx for your post! part1 won't work with notepad++ as i have ROUND BRACKETS ! and for part2 see my EDIT, i had the tags at the wrong positions...

Comment: @zenortheartofregex I fixed the answer both scenarios. Check now

Comment: thank you, fede! the notepad++part is clear to me, for the online demo i'm not sure...

Comment: @zenortheartofregex the online demo is to show your that it works, you only have to copy that regex to Notepad++ and in the Replace field use what I showed in the screenshot on SUBSTITUTION.